# Alternating positions for the page numberings - alternating bottom left and bottom right

Tags: page-numbering, book-design

I finished my diploma thesis a few months ago. I wrote it in a LaTeX-Editor (Overleaf), but the page-numbers are only on the bottom right on each page. Since I wanted to print it like / as a book, I would need the page-numbering of page 2 on the bottom left, the page-numbering of page 3 on the bottom right again and so on; I think you know, how the pagination of a book works. Is this somehow possible to realize this in LaTeX? An easy explanation would be great, since I don't know much about how LaTeX works anymore. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `\documentclass{book}` in place of your class enough?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is quite possible, but the way to get it depends on your document class and the way page numbering is defined. In your case, is it defined with `fancyhdr`?

Comment: Uhm, I'm a bit overwhelmed by those questions. I think my "documentclass" is "scrreprt", if that helps @Bernard

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Not really, I just got some errors like "Command \chapterheadstartvskip undefined.". Since I created my thesis on a template, I may be using some commands that won't work with doc-class "book"

Comment: @Bernard Actually, as I just searched for "fancyhdr" by using Ctrl+F, I found this entry in my "settings" of the document: "\usepackage{fancyhdr}" - so yeah, I think it's defined by fancyhdr.

Comment: I think, this is the way on how the page-numbering works atm: 

\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage{} of\ref{TotPages}} - I already noticed, that the "[R]" stands for right side; I guess I'll have to change that aswell.

Comment: Yes. I think you should use `fancyfoot[RO,LE]{…}`. `RO` stands for Right side on Odd pages and `LE` for ‘Left side on Even pages’.

Comment: @Bernard Yeah, that worked! I also had to change "twoside=false" to "true", but awesome - thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!